# Kalman Filter - When a state model is linear

Tags: nonlinear-system, kalman-filter

I'm a bit confused with the definition of linear model.
[Screenshot from Cornell ppt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKGvx.png)

from 
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4758/2013sp/materials/cs4758_kalmanexamples.pdf

It says that the model is linear. Why? I don't understand how the state model could be linear since we have a cos(t/5).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In this context, it usually means the state response is linear in $(x_0,u)$ where $x_0$ is the initial state and $u$ is the input (a function). Here $u(t) = \cos({t \over 5})$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Copper but I don't think I got the point. Are you saying that the state is linear with respect to the function u(t)? In that case, what would be a non-linear case which we would need to use Extended Kalman Filter ?